# Getting error while publish message to RabbitMQ

Tags: magento2, magento2.4.1, magento-community, rabbit-mq

I am getting an error while publishing a message to RabbitMQ :The connection timed out after 3 sec while awaiting for incoming data.

```php
use Magento\Framework\MessageQueue\PublisherInterface;

$this->publisher->publish('watcher_order_attribute.update', $this->serializer->serialize($publishData));
```

COMMUNICATION.XML

```xml
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Communication/etc/communication.xsd">
    <topic name="watcher_order_attribute.update" request="string" />
</config>
```

queue_topology.xml

```xml
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework-message-queue:etc/topology.xsd">
    <exchange name="magento" type="topic" connection="amqp">
        <binding id="uniqueIdBinding" topic="watcher_order_attribute.update" destinationType="queue" destination="WatcherQueue"/>
    </exchange>
</config>
```

queue_consumer.xml

```xml
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework-message-queue:etc/consumer.xsd">
    <consumer name="vendor.WatcherQueue" queue="WatcherQueue" connection="amqp"  consumerInstance="Magento\Framework\MessageQueue\Consumer" handler="Vendor\MyQueue\Model\Watcher\Attribute\Consumer::process" />
</config>
```

queue_publisher.xml

```xml
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework-message-queue:etc/publisher.xsd">
    <publisher topic="watcher_order_attribute.update">
        <connection name="amqp" exchange="magento" />
    </publisher>
</config>
```

```
'amqp' => [
            'host' => '127.0.0.1',
            'port' => '15672',
            'user' => 'guest',
            'password' => 'guest',
            'virtualhost' => '/'
        ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you please update your **app/etc/env.php** file code, and set the below code.

```
'queue' => [
        'amqp' => [
            'host' => '127.0.0.1',
            'port' => '5672',
            'user' => 'guest',
            'password' => 'guest',
            'virtualhost' => '/'
        ]
    ]
```

Let me know it works. Actually, You have set the wrong port.

**Note:** After updating run the basic CLI command.

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
php bin/magento  setup:static-content:deploy -f
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
php bin/magento cache:clean
php bin/magento cache:flush
```

Comment: I am getting the same error, I tried your given solution as well. unfortunately, it not working in my case. any other idea for same.